# Loss Not changing: Backpropagation in Python 3.6 with MNIST Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, backpropagation, mnist

I set out to learn backpropagation using gradient descend using mathematical approach to get a grasp of how things work without using any libraries like Keras.

I took a sample program from web and made sure I tried to understand each step. It uses following things:
1)3 layer network. Input has 784 columns or features which are pixel values from 0-255
2)1 Hidden node with 250 neurons 
3)1 output node with 1 neuron
4)Weights for both layers generated randomly between -1 and 1
5)Entire batch is fed to the training in each epoch with learning rate 0.1

```
import numpy as np
dataset = np.loadtxt(open("train.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",",skiprows=1,dtype=float)
X = dataset[:,1:]
y = dataset[:,0]
print(X.shape,y.shape)
X = X/255
y = y/10
y = np.reshape(y,(len(y),1)) ## Necessary to avoid mismatching dimensions

def sigmoid(x, derive=False):
   if derive:
     return x * (1 - x)
   return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

# Define a learning rate
eta = 0.1
# Define the number of epochs for learning
epochs = 500000


w01 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(784,250))
w12 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(250,1))
# Start feeding forward and backpropagate *epochs* times.
for epoch in range(epochs):
   # Feed forward
   z_h = np.dot(X, w01)
   a_h = sigmoid(z_h)
   z_o = np.dot(a_h, w12)
   a_o = sigmoid(z_o)
   # Calculate the error
   a_o_error = ((1 / 2) * (np.power((a_o - y), 2)))
   #a_o_error = y-a_o
   # Backpropagation
   ## Output layer
   delta_a_o_error = a_o - y
   delta_z_o = sigmoid(a_o,derive=True)
   delta_w12 = a_h
   delta_output_layer = np.dot(delta_w12.T,(delta_a_o_error * delta_z_o))

   ## Hidden layer
   delta_a_h = np.dot(delta_a_o_error * delta_z_o, w12.T)
   delta_z_h = sigmoid(a_h,derive=True)
   delta_w01 = X
   delta_hidden_layer = np.dot(delta_w01.T, delta_a_h * delta_z_h)
   w01 = w01 - eta * delta_hidden_layer
   w12 = w12 - eta * delta_output_layer
   if epoch % 100 == 0:    
     print ("Loss at epoch "+str(epoch)+":"+str(np.mean(np.square(y - a_o))))


#Testing:
X_Test = X[129] 
Y_Test = y[129]  

z_h = np.dot(X_Test, w01)
a_h = sigmoid(z_h)
z_o = np.dot(a_h, w12)
a_o = sigmoid(z_o)

print("Expected Output:",Y_Test*10) 
print("Actual Output got:",a_o*10)
```

Here is my problem:
1) I cannot feed entire MNIST dataset with 42k samples as I believe neural network works better with mini-batches plus I need to do quick POCs with smaller dataset
2)I reduce the total inputs to 500 rows and the NN correctly predicts a digit fed from any of the inputs rows
3)However, when I increase the sample inputs to close to 3k, the loss does not change at all. I tried playing with learning rate or number of hidden layer neurons but no change

Data can be downloaded from:
www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data

I trimmed the train.csv file to around 3k rows so that I can feed it.

Can someone please help me understand this better on what can make this work with my sample dataset. I have already spent a week on it and still not giving up, the only thing I can try and implement is creating mini-batches inside this program but still evaluating on how to do that because I am not from programming background.

Thank you for reading my question and your patience.

Regards
Chandan Jha

Comment: Could you please add the output too? When loss is not changing.

Comment: Hi Vikas, I see following messages repeatedly since 1st epoch: 
Loss at epoch 59800 is:0.285596560373

Comment: It also means the program was still running and at the end it just tries to predict using a random row which I hardcoded in the program for now only to output a garbage value. I know that many folks use vector identity matrix for multi class output like this but I tried using a single output neuron and it worked with 500 sample size.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions for what I believe can improve your implementation:

1. For MNIST dataset, consider using the [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) regression function in the final layer rather than the sigmoid. You have multiple classes(0, 1, 2,...9) to which given input may belong to. Sigmoid - a binary classifier is not useful in this case. With Softmax, your output will be the digit with maximum probability from 10 possibilities(0-9).
2. Preprocess your labels of the dataset into one-hot vector format(In which each label would be a vector of size 10 and the only the index with desired output number will be 1, rest 0's)
3. Unless you get stuck in local minima with plain batch gradient descent, you should observe some reduction in loss over the iterations.
   Using mini-batch may help to converge in robust manner.
   You can use your existing code mentioned above and put in a structure like:

```py
    start_pos = 0
    mini_batch_size = 64 #Use suitable batch size that would fit in your memory(Typically use 
                    #size that is a power of 2)
    num_complete_batches = int(len(X) / mini_batch_size)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for curr_batch in range(num_complete_batches):
            current_x = X[:, curr_batch*mini_batch_size : curr_batch*mini_batch_size + \
                        mini_batch_size]
            current_y = Y[:, curr_batch*mini_batch_size : curr_batch*mini_batch_size + \
                        mini_batch_size]
            #Forward-Backward pass
        #If you have left-over examples that did not fit in complete batches, now feed those 
        #into the network
```

4. Use deeper network.

Comment: Thank you Jaideep. I will implement your suggestion soon on this and update.